# setting up email with domain (opencart)

Tags: email, dns, opencart

I've started running a business online and need some help with correctly setting up my email accounts.

Currently my website is hosted by 000webhost which isn't great but is doing the job at the moment before i port over to a paid hosting service.

My domain was purchased on 1and1.co.uk which forwards users to my opencart website which is configured to always have the paid domain show in the address bar.

When configuring my email 1and1 don't have a service that allows me to send outgoing email unless i sign up to a paid mailbox. I currently forward all emails that go to sales@xxxxx.com to my free email address which is sales@xxxxx.xxxx.com.

Emails that get sent directly from opencart such as orders etc seem to be going from sales@xxxxx.com. How can i compose emails to be sent from this domain email address as well instead of using the free one which isn't a perfect email address.

Answer (score 1):

The email address it displays as being sent from is the one you set in your settings under `SYSTEM > SETTINGS` in the admin. Simply change that and it should use it in all outgoing mail

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. The emails that are getting sent from opencart are being sent from the correct email address as intended such as when new orders are placed. Its the custom emails that i need to send e.g. when a customer makes an enquiry on the website that needs a custom answer. The only way of replying to this so far has been through 000webhosts emails

Comment: @green4rrow - Can't you get SMTP details from 000webhost for this? If not then I'm not sure it will be possible